# will jquery triggers any event after it loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I want to run some code after jquery load. Will jquery fires any event after it is completely loaded. I don't want to wait until the document ready event.
There are lot of javascripts in my case and I want to do some operation after jquery loaded. I won't be able to keep this function right after jquery. So I want a event so that I can perform the function once jquery loaded

Comment: I'm a little confused by the question. Can you be more specific about what event you're trying to fire.

Comment: you can use onload function and add your events

Comment: See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.holdReady

Answer (score 0):

The reason for writing your jQuery inside document ready is to ensure that you don't get an error by trying to select a DOM element that isn't in the document yet. So if you're event involves some DOM element not waiting for document ready could cause an error.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a time where I would trigger a custom event that will run just before `$(document).ready()` triggers.
So, somewhere else in your code, instead of using `$(document).ready`, you would use:

```
$(window).bind('setup', function() {
    //code here...
});
```

And / Or

```
$(window).bind('loaded', function() {
    //any other code here...
});
```

And in your one and only `ready` handler, you'd do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).trigger('setup');
    $(window).trigger('loaded'):
});
```